# Javascript object properties assigned values from other uncalled functions when constructed

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor, prototype

I have a particle system class that I am trying to initialize, however whenever I call the constructor, it sets values for arrays of the class that are explicitly declared as empty in the constructor. This is my code:

```
function partSys(pcount, fcount, wcount){
  //Number of particles, force-applying objects, and constraings
  this.partCount = pcount;
  this.forcerCount = fcount;
  this.wallCount = wcount;

  //State variables
  this.s0 = [];
  this.s0dot = [];
  this.s1 = [];

  //Collection of force-applying objects
  this.f0 = [];

  //Collection of constraint-applying objects
  this.c0 = [];

  console.log(this.s0);
  console.log(this);
}

partSys.prototype.constructor = partSys;
partSys.prototype.init = function(){
  //Create partCount # of particles
  for (var i = 0; i < this.partCount; i++){  //partCount = 100
    this.s0.push(new CPart());
    this.s0dot.push(new CPart());
    this.s1.push(new CPart());
  }
  //Add gravity
  this.f0.push(new CForcer());
}
```

Later on I call them like this:

```
boxSys = new partSys(100, 1, 1);
console.log(boxSys);
boxSys.init();
```

I have no idea why (maybe something with prototypes?), but the code for the init() is setting the values for a created partSys object before I even call init().

console.log(this.s0) correctly returns [], but when I call console.log(this) in the constructor, it returns an object that has s0: Array[0] but becomes s0:Array[100] when expanded. Why might this be happening?? Thanks in advance

```
partSys {partCount: 100, forcerCount: 1, wallCount: 1, s0: Array[0], s0dot: Array[0]…}
c0: Array[0]
f0: Array[1]
forcerCount: 1
partCount: 100
s0: Array[100]
0: CPart
1: CPart
2: CPart
3: CPart
4: CPart
5: CPart
```

Comment: but if you remove boxSys.init(); will it be right output?

Comment: Yeah, when I comment it out everything correctly initializes as empty

Comment: okay, the problem, that console.log() shows current status of object, so first iteration of console.log() will show you object, but when object get updated, value of object in console will get updated too. so if you need, you can console.log() array inside of object, that will show you real info on first iteration

Comment: above I had a console.log(this.s0) and console.log(this) inside the constructor of the object, is that what you mean? I'm using the constructor to declare the object

Comment: yes, console.log(this.s0) will show real info on iteration, console.log(this) will show updated info

Comment: console.log(this.s0) in the constructor displays an array of size 100 despite being immediately after the declaration this.s0 = []. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: tried your code http://jsfiddle.net/wKZ8Q/ it displays empty arrray on first iteration for me